# Opendaylight controller. What is the difference?

Tags: sdn, opendaylight

I am building a test SDN system using Opendaylight controller. Right now I am using lithium release and making 3-node cluster. After reading some material, I encountered this page - https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_SDN_Controller_Platform_(OSCP):Installation.

So, question - what is the difference between just the plane opendaylight controller distribution and this opendaylight sdn controller platform? Is the second one just an old thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Opendaylight SDN Controller Platform (OSCP) project is not active and is not part of any of the OpenDaylight releases. It was originally contributed by engineers from Big Switch Networks, but later they decided not to participate in the Opendaylight releases. Even though the code and branch are still present, it is not under active development/contribution. OSCP does not integrate with OVSDB or Openflow13 or VTN. it is a standalone project and is not part of any of the releases.

The Opendaylight controller (Lithium) is the most recent Opendaylight controller official release that the one should use.